# Tolerant phrase search

Tags: solr, lucene

How do I perform a solr search for a phrase like "the quick brown fox" allowing *n* words to miss, such that the following strings will be found (for *n* = 2):

- "the quick brown fox"
- "the quick brown "
- "the quick fox"
- "quick brown fox"
- "the brown fox"
- "the quick"
- "the brown"
- "the fox"
- "quick brown"
- "quick fox"
- "brown fox"

I'd like to pass *n* as a parameter. Can this problem be solved with slop?

Comment: Can you please elaborate what $n$ actually means?

Comment: You want to search a set of documents. You pass a search phrase and you also pass the number of words (n) that should match. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: Sorry for not being specific enough: I pass a search phrase, and I pass the number *n* of words that are *allowed to miss*. But the order of the words is supposed to be significant. And the remaining words should match exactly. (This is why I don't want to call a fuzzy phrase search.)

Comment: I feel you might have to write your own tokenizer which would index each word with every other in the same sequence they appear. Also it should combine in 1's, 2's, 3's etc. and then the search phrase should be matched with those combinations only which are of the same length as the value of n.

Comment: For me as a beginner this sounds much too complicated. I am looking for something out of the box. But maybe there isn't such? (I found the requirement quite simple and natural.... - something like fuzzy search for phrases.)

Comment: The tokenizer would be combination of the Position Filter Factory and the Shingle Filter. However this will make your index too large.

Answer (score 0):

You can check for the Edismax parser, which will allow you to specify the [minimum match](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/ExtendedDisMax#mm_.28Minimum_.27Should.27_Match.29) parameter to tune the number of the words you want to match in the query.

You can define a default value and have it overriding with the query everytime.

You can also check for using Stopwords filter for `the` so that it does not need to match at all.